# How to push sub-ViewControllers without NavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I want to push viewControllers to an area on my main viewController. From what I understand, you can't use a NavigationController unless you are adding it to a UIWindow.

This animation reminds of UIScrollView horizontal scrolling. But I want it to work like a NavigationController instead. The ViewControllers will be changed when the user presses on  specific actions.

ViewController2 is going to be a tableView with some other buttons.

ViewController3 is going to be a form to change the object from the tableView.

[image: Animation of viewControllers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Actually solved it by playing around with UIView Animations.

```
-(void)slideInView:(UIView*)newView toView:(UIView*)oldView {
    /* Sets the view outside the right edge and adds it to mainView */
    newView.bounds = mainView.bounds;
    newView.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x + 784, newView.frame.origin.y, newView.frame.size.width, newView.frame.size.height);
    [mainView addSubview:newView];

    /* Begin transition */
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Slide Left" context:oldView];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(slideInCompleted:finished:context:)];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    newView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, newView.frame.size.width, newView.frame.size.height);
    oldView.frame = CGRectMake(oldView.frame.origin.x - 784, oldView.frame.origin.y, oldView.frame.size.width, oldView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)slideInCompleted:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    UIView *view = (UIView*)context;
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and to use it

```
menuController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
[self slideOutView:menuController.view toView:loginController.view];
[oldController release];
```

Remeber that you have alloced a UIViewController that you need to release when you are done useing it! In example i'm done with loginController and releasing it.

Comment: `retainCount` is useless. Don't call it.

Comment: It's not as long as you know how to use it. Also it wasn't suppose to be there tho, thanks for notice.

Comment: If you know how to use retainCount, you would know never to use it.  There is always a better way save for exceedingly rare situations.

Answer (score 7):

I recently found a method in UIView that creates a "push or pop" feel to switching views.

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

This is straight out of the UIView documentation, so I would recommend looking at the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to see the specifics.  Basically, it switches a view to another view, while the `options:` section lets you pick from a multitude of different styles.

Comment: Do you know how to do a 'slide' using this method?

Comment: @DanyalAytekin that last i looked, there was no way to transition via a slide, but there may be updated options now that work with the iOS 7 schema. [UIViewAnimationOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions) would be a good place to look. It may also be possible to override the animation and insert your own, though that may not be the best idea as it could get messy.

Comment: Thanks @slev. I don't think there is one built-in. I ended up coding a simple animation.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no way to "push" **natively** any controller without a `UINavigationController`. You can however, animate views in and out.

With the example you have posted, it looks like a simple `UIScrollView` would be your easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

I’d use a UIScrollView, as it has the ability to do snapping to "pages" built in. You can also scroll to any part with setContentOffset:animated: as well.